# Identify duplicates based on grouping

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

I need to identify duplicates based on a given condition and filter out the records based on the condition:-

We need to first group the records based on the campaign name first and then the remaining columns to find the duplicates.

The camapign name can be broken down in 3 parts - `{prefix + keyword + suffix}`. The keywords are - "shoes", "apparel" and "watch".
Hence, for instance: campaign name "**Gen_X_Shoes_TTU_Bing**" means keyword is "**shoes**" and prefix is "**Gen_X**" and suffix is "**TTU_bing**".

If these groupings are the same between any records and the remaining fields (advertiser etc) are also identical we consider it as duplicate.

Once the duplicates have been identified we retain only 1 record from the duplicate group based on the priority of the keyword.

Priority :

```
1) Shoes
2) Apparel
3) Watch
```

Consider the following:

```
adverstiser | shopid | campaign               | customerid
ABC1        | XYZ1   | Gen_X_Shoes_TTU_Bing   | cust123
ABC1        | XYZ1   | Gen_X_Apparel_TTU_Bing | cust123
ABC2        | XYZ2   | Zen_X_Watch_SKU_Gogl   | cust456
ABC2        | XYZ2   | Zen_X_Apparel_SKU_Gogl | cust456
ABC3        | XYZ3   | Gen_Z_Watch_INL_Gogl   | cust567
```

Considering the first and the 2nd records, the prefix of the campaign containing keyword "shoes" is "Gen_X_" and the suffix is "TTU_bing" which matches exactly with each other and also all other columns are also identical.
Hence, these 2 records can be considered as duplicates and the output will be the first record since it contains "*Shoes*" which has a higher priority than the keyword "Apparel"

Similarly, considering the 3rd and 4th record, the prefix of the campaign is "Zen_X" and suffix is "SKU_Gogl" which matches for both the records and also the other columns are identical.
Hence, these 2 records can be considered as duplicates ann the output will be the record containing the keyword "Apparel".

Finally, the 5th record doesnot find any matches hence will be output as is.

Output:

```
adverstiser | shopid | campaign               | customerid
ABC1        | XYZ1   | Gen_X_Shoes_TTU_Bing   | cust123
ABC2        | XYZ2   | Zen_X_Apparel_SKU_Gogl | cust456
ABC3        | XYZ3   | Gen_Z_Watch_INL_Gogl   | cust567
```

Requirement 2:

Each of the records which are selected in the output needs to be duplicated
with an additional column, "action", having values "set" and "ready" in each of them.
Can anyone please help me. Happy to provide more clarity if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can create columns that hold the keyword (extracted using `regex_extract()`) and the suffix/prefix combination (dervived using `regex_replace()`), and then use a windowing function to select the first row per group. Note that to get the keyword in the correct order, I replace it with "1", "2", "3".

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

(
    df
    .withColumn("suffpre", F.regexp_replace(F.col("campaign"), "Shoes|Apparel|Watch", ""))
    .withColumn("keyword", F.regexp_extract(F.col("campaign"), "Shoes|Apparel|Watch", idx=0))
    .withColumn("keyword", F.when(F.col("keyword")=="Shoes","1").when(F.col("keyword")=="Apparel","2").otherwise("3"))
    .withColumn("r", F.row_number().over(
        Window
        .partitionBy(["advertiser", "shopid","customerid", "suffpre"])
        .orderBy(F.col("keyword"))))
    .filter(F.col("r")==1)
    .drop("r", "suffpre", "keyword")
).show()
```

Output:

```
|advertiser|shopid|            campaign|customerid|
+----------+------+--------------------+----------+
|      ABC1|  XYZ1|Gen_X_Shoes_TTU_Bing|   cust123|
|      ABC2|  XYZ2|Zen_X_Apparel_SKU...|   cust456|
|      ABC3|  XYZ3|Gen_Z_Watch_INL_Gogl|   cust567|
+----------+------+--------------------+----------+
```

If you want to duplicate this record set, adding an indicator column `action` with values `set` and `ready`, you can do as follows..

Assuming `k` is the result from above:

```
(
    k
    .withColumn("action", F.lit("set"))
    .unionAll(
        k.withColumn("action", F.lit("ready"))
    )
).show()
```

Output:

```
|advertiser|shopid|            campaign|customerid|action|
+----------+------+--------------------+----------+------+
|      ABC1|  XYZ1|Gen_X_Shoes_TTU_Bing|   cust123|   set|
|      ABC2|  XYZ2|Zen_X_Apparel_SKU...|   cust456|   set|
|      ABC3|  XYZ3|Gen_Z_Watch_INL_Gogl|   cust567|   set|
|      ABC1|  XYZ1|Gen_X_Shoes_TTU_Bing|   cust123| ready|
|      ABC2|  XYZ2|Zen_X_Apparel_SKU...|   cust456| ready|
|      ABC3|  XYZ3|Gen_Z_Watch_INL_Gogl|   cust567| ready|
+----------+------+--------------------+----------+------+
```

Comment: why are you suppressing the values of the prefix and the suffix ? those will be required to identify the duplicate group. Please correct me if i m wrong... Also, please let me know what `idx=0` means in this context.. im bit confused about the first 2 lines of the code... sorry very new to PySpark :-(

Comment: not sure what you mean by supressing?  I create the column suffpre that holds the suff and pre, which is required to define the group (and I use it in the Window() function where i specify the partition over which I want to order the keyword.   In regexp_extract() function, i specify which instance of the regex match I want to extract, by indicating its index. idx=0 means the first index.  I drop the r, suffpre, and keyword columns because you indicated they should not be in the final output

Comment: Also, as an additional requirement - can we duplicate the rows which we get from `col("r") == 1` into 2 records each with an additional column "action" with value as 'set' and the for the other duplicated record, "action" = 'ready'. I have updated the requirement in the question.

Comment: Normally, you should open another question, rather than add a completely new issue to the original question. However, in this case, I've provided the addition you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you... can you please take a look at another question - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77065111/filtering-data-based-on-variable-number-of-arguments`