# Filtering data based on variable number of arguments

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a requirement to filter data based on variable number of arguments. Basically, I am reading a table and I want to filter the data based on multiple regions that would be provided through a parameter in the function. The number of regions passed to the function could be variable. The region column would contain a string and we have to find the searched string in the that string.

Something as :

```
def read_regions(*regions):
    df = spark.read.table("my_input_table").filter(col("region").contains(*regions))
    return df
```

The function could be called as :

```
data = read_regions('US')
```

OR

```
data = read_regions('CHN', 'NL', 'ES')
```

Or with any number of regions. The data should be filtered accordingly and data returned.

Can someone please help

So, I want the data to be filtered based on the arguments passed to the function.

### UPDATE:

Search strings -> `'USA', 'CHN'`

Input:

```
orderid | campaign        | custid
1234    | Gen_X_USA_offr1 | c2234
5678    | Gen_Z_CHN_offr2 | c1345
7893    | Gen_X_EU_Tru2   | c4563
```

Output:

```
orderid | campaign        | custid
1234    | Gen_X_USA_offr1 | c2234
5678    | Gen_Z_CHN_offr2 | c1345
```

In above, the first 2records are selected in the output since the "campaign" column contains our search regions - 'USA' and 'CHN'. The third row is not selected into the output as it does not contain the search regions.

Happy to provide more clarification if required.

Thanks

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

For a partial string match you have a few options. If you want to stick with the python API you could use functools `reduce` with `or_` from opeartor:

```py
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def read_regions(*regions):
    df = spark.read.table("my_input_table")
    df = df.filter(reduce(or_, [F.col("region").contains(r) for r in regions])
    return df
```

You could also do this with SQL filtering in the `.filter` method:

```
def read_regions(*regions):
    df = spark.read.table("my_input_table")
    df = df.filter(" OR ".join([f"region LIKE '%{r}%'" for r in regions]))
    return df
```

If you were searching for an exact string match you could use `.isin(*cols)` for this.

```
def read_regions(*regions):
    df = spark.read.table("my_input_table")
    df = df.filter(col("region").isin(*regions))
    return df
```

See the docs here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html

Comment: it fails with the error: `org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException: [UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE.LITERAL_TYPE] The feature is not supported: Literal for 'US, CHN' of class java.util.ArrayList`. is there a specific way to pass the region names to the function ?

Comment: Sorry, missing asterisk in the .isin call - I've edited the answer so it should work for you now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i have to search the value in a string in the column. For instance, I have to search for `USA` in the value `Gen_X_TTU_USA_OFFR`. But using `isin()` will try for an exact match which will not help in this case. We have to search for the given string instead.

Comment: Ok, that's a slightly different problem than I thought. If you add an example of your input and expected output that would help frame it.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: That's clear now, thank you. I've updated the answer with a couple of options for you.

Comment: I used your solution with the `Like` operator. Thanks. However, I have got one more problem in my hand. Is there anyway, I could make the search literal ? I mean I provided a search string as `'_ES_'` in the hope that it will find matches like `'Gen_Z_ES_Sale_199'`, which is working correctly, but, it is also picking up records such as 'Gen_X_Test_1R'. It is considering the underscore as a wild-card and and not  a literal and returning strings with the word `'Test'` in it. Can it be done so that `_ES_` is searched but not`Test` ? Please let me know if I need to update the question.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. You have to escape the underscore with \, e.g. `\_ES\_`. Here's the docs on like: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-like.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rlike` function for this case. It is also known as the regex like.

```
def read_regions(*regions):
    df = spark.read.table("my_input_table").filter(col("region").rlike(f"({'|'.join(regions)})"))
    return df
```

For more information check the docs at:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python//reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.rlike.html